# Pressing a key combination(e.g. Ctrl+Alt+x) automatically when a certain cell's value = "1"

Tags: excel, vba

I want the computer to press a certain key combination (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+x) automatically right after a certain cell(e.g. A1)'s value in an excel worksheet is changed to a certain value(e.g."1"). 
I have searched the Internet for hours but I couldn't find the information exactly same as my situation. Please help and thanks a lot.

Comment: `Ctrl+x` is the command for `cut`.  Could you just use something like `Range("A1").Cut Destination:=Range("A2")` for example?

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't use Ctrl+x as an example. I am not going to perform a cut action but just want the computer to press a key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need to enter a key combination, but if you really want to it's `SendKeys`. 
This code will perform a number of actions depending on the value entered in cell A1 finishing with a SendKeys command:

```
'Fires when you change a value on the sheet.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Was only a single cell selected?
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        'Was the value changed (Target) in range A1?
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
            'Perform an action depending on Targets value.
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case 1
                    'Cut the Target cell (Ctrl+x).
                    Target.Cut
                Case 2
                    'Copy the Target cell (Ctrl+c).
                    Target.Copy
                Case 3
                    'Filldown from the Target 10 rows.
                    Target.Resize(10).FillDown
                Case 4
                    'Change the font colour to red.
                    Target.Font.Color = vbRed
                Case "Hello"
                    'Change the contents of the cell.
                    'This will cause the Change event to fire again, so disable events first.
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Value = "Goodbye"
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                Case Else
                    'If anything else is press keys Right Arrow, Up Arrow, F2.
                    SendKeys "{RIGHT}{UP}{F2}"
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code doesn't work if cell A1 is a formula, say "=B1+C1". Sorry that I forgot to mention that. Please help again.

Comment: To fire when a formula updates you'll have to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.  You don't get the `Target` argument with that though, so you'll have to check a specific cell, if it's the value you want then select that cell and then use `SendKeys`.  But as I said, there's probably a better way to do it then SendKeys anyway.  If you update your original question to what the end result you're after is then the On  Hold status will probably get removed.